# Gmail site doesn't open up after submitting the form

Tags: html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To Contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>THE FORM</h1>
  <hr>
  <form action="mailto:debiocbkr@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <label>Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Your Name" value=""><br>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="Email" value=""><br>
    <label>Your Message:</label><br>
    <textarea name="Your Message:" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

After clicking the submit button, the response should be opening of the Gmail webpage, but it opens up nothing. It doesn't respond at all.

Comment: Why do you think Gmail should open? Maybe on your browser it could happen if Gmail set up as default email client but it won't happen on any other person's browser.

Comment: What should I do?